# TFS Build step for replace file name from Service-AMR.deploy to Service.deploy

Tags: replace, tfs, build-definition

I am new for creation of NuGet Package. Somehow I managed to create NuGet Package as my solution. But, I am facing few problems in my solution. Based on regions, I am using the configuration file. for example, i am having following config files in my solution.

1) Service-AMR.config
2) Service-EUR.config

During build, i want to convert above files to service.config in AMR folder and same for another one. I have tried **copy files** task and failed.

Please help., Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add some code of what you are trying to do.. This is not enough information for solving your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Actually, i haven't write any code for that and i am just using Visual studio Team Foundation server 2015 URL for Build definition creation. Please let me know how to use code for this.

Comment: Are you going to replace tokens in config  files with variable values or just want to rename a file name on the build agent during build pipeline?

Comment: @Sathish Have you resolved the issue by  Patrick's answer below? any update?

Comment: Thanks, Guys! I have replaced the file names using powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

To simply rename a file name on the build agent, you could use `cmd.exe` in a command line task to rename files.  Here's an example :

Arguments: String.Format("/c rename ""{0}"" ""{1}""","currentname.config","newname.config")

FileName: "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

WorkingDirectory: "C:\Windows\System32"